# Multiple Google Projects in New Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a new Google account and used it to sign up for Google Cloud. I ensured two-factor authentication and have yet to set up billing (thankfully). When I logged in, I noticed a list of projects and I don't know where they came from. Somewhere I saw mention of this occurring if I had subscribed to a topic in Google groups which I have not (new account). Is this normal behavior?

[image]

Comment: One possibility is the **public** Google projects that you have free access to. Your question has no details to help you determine if you have a problem or not.

Comment: I created a new Cloud account with a new Google account. I have only one project: My First Project. I'm going to give it some time and see whether I have similar results. Thank you for your suggestion that these may be public though I'm only used to seeing one project.

Comment: You can try `gcloud compute project-info  describe --project myProjectID`  to display all data associated with the Compute Engine project resource. The project resource contains data such as global quotas, common instance metadata, and the project's creation time.